# Count number of consecutive True in column, restart when False

Tags: python, pandas

I work with the following column in a pandas df:

```
A
True
True
True
False
True
True
```

I want to add column B that counts the number of consecutive "True" in A. I want to restart everytime a "False" comes up. Desired output:

```
A      B
True   1
True   2
True   3
False  0
True   1
True   2
```

Comment: Please post if have any code error or  code samples you already written?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `cumsum` identify the blocks of rows where the values in column `A` stays `True`, then group the column `A` on these blocks and calculate cumulative sum to assign ordinal numbers

```
df['B'] = df['A'].groupby((~df['A']).cumsum()).cumsum()
```

---

```
       A  B
0   True  1
1   True  2
2   True  3
3  False  0
4   True  1
5   True  2
```

Comment: Downvoter, I really don't care about the downvotes, you can give as many as you want but please don't give downvotes to the new contributors this will discourage them from participation in SO.

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple & native approach

(For a small code sample it worked fine)

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [True, False, True, True, True, False, True, True]})

class ToNums:
  counter = 0
  @staticmethod
  def convert(bool_val):
    if bool_val:
      ToNums.counter += 1
    else:
      ToNums.counter = 0
    return ToNums.counter

df['B'] = df.A.map(ToNums.convert)

df
```

```sh
     A      B
0   True    1
1   False   0
2   True    1
3   True    2
4   True    3
5   False   0
6   True    1
7   True    2
```

Comment: There are systematic downvotes without explanation lately, I've had a lot myself. I upvoted you to compensate.

Comment: That's new, I've upvoted to compensate for you aswell @mozway

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example

```
v=0
for i,val in enumerate(df['A']):
    if val =="True":
        df.loc[i,"C"]= v =v+1
    else:
        df.loc[i,"C"]=v=0
df.head()
```

This will give the desired output

```
    A        C
0   True     1
1   True     2
2   True     3
3   False    0
4   True     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `groupby`, `cumsum`, and `cumcount`

```
df['B'] = (df.groupby((df['A']&
                      ~df['A'].shift(1).fillna(False) # row is True and next is False
                     )
                     .cumsum() # make group id
                     )
             .cumcount().add(1) # make cumulated count
             *df['A'] # multiply by 0 where initially False, 1 otherwise
           )
```

output:

```
       A  B
0   True  1
1   True  2
2   True  3
3  False  0
4   True  1
5   True  2
```